# How to remove protected package using microdnf

Tags: rhel, dnf

How a protected package can be removed using microdnf package manager?

When running docker container `almalinux/9-minimal` (or `redhat/ubi9-minimal`) like

```
podman run -it --rm almalinux/9-minimal
```

and inside the container

```
microdnf install -y dnf && microdnf remove -y dnf
```

the latter command fails with

```
error: Could not depsolve transaction; 1 problem detected:
 Problem: The operation would result in removing the following protected packages: dnf
```